# session in silverlight using Isolated Storage

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

in mainpage.xaml.cs (login page) I am setting up a session variable using isolted storage

```
private IsolatedStorageSettings app = IsolatedStorageSettings.SiteSettings;
app["LoginId"] = txtUname.Text;
```

how can I get that "LoginId" in the next page.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:-

```
private IsolatedStorageSettings app = IsolatedStorageSettings.SiteSettings;
string loginId = app["LoginId"];
```

?

That should work fine.

Note that if you are delivering your app entirely in Silverlight then you should consider using Silverlight's navigation framework so that you are not actually re-loading various Xaps as you navigate.